# Retrieve default belongs_to record from a built has_many association in a before_create hook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have 2 models, `User` and `Stash`.

A User has many stashes, and a default_stash. A Stash has one owner (User).

Before a User is created I want it to build a Stash AND assign that Stash to self.default_stash. As per the instructions here [Rails - Best-Practice: How to create dependent has_one relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808782/rails-best-practice-how-to-create-dependent-has-one-relations) I created the Stash relation, however I cannot 'create' the belongs_to relation at the same time.

**User.rb**

```
has_many :stashes, foreign_key: :owner_id
belongs_to :default_stash, class_name: 'Stash', foreign_key: :owner_id

before_create :build_default_stash
def build_default_stash
  self.default_stash = stashes.build
  true
end
```

**Stash.rb**

```
belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
```

At this point the Stash can be found in `user.stashes` but `user.default_stash` remains nil, as `stashes.build` does not return an id in the before_create block.

What I need can be achieved by adding the following to **User.rb**

```
after_create :force_assign_default_stash
def force_assign_default_stash
  update_attribute(:default_stash, stashes.first)
end
```

But I'd much prefer to keep everything within the `before_create` block if possible, for validations etc.

Comment: If a user belongs to a default_stash, it must also have a default_stash_id, and therefore doesn't use a foreign key into the default_stash table (owner_id). I think what you mean is a user has_one default_stash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you that what you describe *should* work, but if you're building associated records in memory and expecting them to save together properly -- with everything hooked up -- then ActiveRecord is particularly finicky about how you define them.

But you *can* make it work without changing a thing in your `before_create`.

The usual problem is that you need to give AR hints about which relationships are inverses of each other. The `has_many` and `belongs_to` methods take an `:inverse_of` option. The problem in your case is that you have one side of a relationship (`Stash#owner`) that is actually the inverse of two on the other (`User#stashes` and `User#default_stash`), so what would you set as the `inverse_of` for `Stash#owner`?

The solution is to add a `has_one` to Stash (call it something like `owner_as_default`), to balance things out. Then you can add `inverse_of` to all of the definitions, each identifying its inverse on the other side. The end result is this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :stashes,       foreign_key: :owner_id, inverse_of: :owner
  belongs_to :default_stash, class_name: "Stash",    inverse_of: :owner_as_default

  ...
end

class Stash < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner,            class_name: "User", inverse_of: :stashes
  has_one    :owner_as_default, class_name: "User",
    foreign_key: :default_stash_id, inverse_of: :default_stash
end
```

(Also, you don't need a foreign key on your belongs_to.)

From there, your `before_create` should work as you've written it.

Yes, it seems that this is a lot of redundant defining. Can't ActiveRecord figure it all out from the foreign keys and whatnot? I always feel like I'm breaking some walls by making one side so aware of what it's the inverse of. Maybe in some future version of Rails this will be ironed out.

Comment: This works great and makes sense, I don't mind helping ActiveRecord out a bit when it is doing so much legwork behind the scenes! Thanks Rob.