# Set attributes when automatically building has_one child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, attributes, nested-attributes

I'm attempting to automatically build a child model when its parent is created, as noted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3809360/2540204).  Say I have two models `Person` `has_one :folder` and I would like to create a folder when the person creates  To do this I go into the `Person` model and (from the example above) do the following.

```
has_one :folder
before_create :build_default_folder

private
def build_default_folder
  build_folder
  true
end
```

This makes sense, but say `Profile` had some attributes that I would like to set an attribute for `Folder` based on the `Person`'s attributes.  Like if the person has `:person_name` what should I do to set `:folder_name` as "[person_name]'s_Folder"?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You able to access a parent attribute from the child model:

```
class Profile < AR::Base
    has_one :folder
    before_create :build_default_folder

    private
    def build_default_folder
      build_folder(folder_name: person_name)
      true
    end
end
```

Read the documentation for [`Active Record Associations`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  If this was in the person model wouldn't that be `build_folder(folder_name: self.person_name)`?  Or am I mistaken?

Comment: yeah, my bad, you can use both`self.person_name` and `person_name`.